# Formula field in SOQL query

Tags: soql, formula

If I am querying a formula field in `SOQL`, then will it always return latest value based on data? If not then what value it will show?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Formula fields are calculated at the time of query, so they will calculate at runtime based on the currently saved values for that record.

Answer (score 2):

[Working with SOQL and SOSL Query Results](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_working_with_results.htm)
 states, in part (emphasis mine):

> Also note that sObject **fields that contain formulas return the value of the field at the time the SOQL or SOSL query was issued**. Any changes to other fields that are used within the formula are not reflected in the formula field value until the record has been saved and re-queried in Apex. Like other read-only sObject fields, the values of the formula fields themselves cannot be changed in Apex.

Comment: Does this mean, a formula field won't have any value in the before-insert context of a trigger?

Comment: It's been a while since I checked, but I believe at least formulas with no cross-object reference should be populated or work with `recalculateFormulas` even in `before insert` context.